# Arduino board with StandardFirmata doesn't respond to C# and Python client

Tags: serial, usb, uart, firmata, seeeduino-xiao

I have a Seeeduino XIAO board with Firmata running on it. I'm currently trying to write C# client to communicate with this board.
I have tried using [Iot.Device.Arduino](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/iot.device.arduino?view=iot-dotnet-latest), [SolidSolis.Arduino](https://github.com/SolidSoils/Arduino) and *pyfirmata* for that purpose but I'm struggling with problem - board doesn't respond to any requests sent by my apps.

However, when I use [Windows Remote Arduino Experience](https://apps.microsoft.com/detail/9nblggh2041m?hl=en-us&gl=US) app, board is being successfuly found and I can control pins, retrieve info etc. [image: Screenshot 1]
[image: Screenshot 2]

- I use these programs to communicate with board:

```csharp
using Iot.Device.Arduino;

var arduino = new ArduinoBoard("COM3", 57600);
Console.WriteLine(arduino.FirmataVersion.Major); // This throws System.TimeoutException
```

```python
import pyfirmata
port = 'COM3'
board = pyfirmata.Arduino(port)
print(board.firmata_version) # prints 'None'
```

- [StandardFirmata](https://github.com/firmata/arduino/blob/main/examples/StandardFirmata/StandardFirmata.ino) runs on Arduino.
- This was added into `Boards.h`:

```cpp
#elif defined(SEEED_XIAO_M0)
#define TOTAL_ANALOG_PINS 11
#define TOTAL_PINS 17 // 11 digital / analog + 1 DAC output + 2 i2c + 3 spi
#define VERSION_BLINK_PIN LED_BUILTIN
#define PIN_SERIAL1_RX 7
#define PIN_SERIAL1_TX 6
#define IS_PIN_DIGITAL(p) ((p) >= 0 && (p) <= 10)
#define IS_PIN_ANALOG(p) ((p) >= 0 && (p) <= 10)
#define IS_PIN_PWM(p) ((p) >= 1 && (p) <= 10)
#define IS_PIN_SERVO(p) (IS_PIN_DIGITAL(p) && (p) < MAX_SERVOS) // deprecated since v2.4
#define IS_PIN_I2C(p) ((p) == 4 || (p) == 5) // SDA = 4, SCL = 5
#define IS_PIN_SPI(p) ((p) == 4 || (p) == 10 || (p) == 9 || (p) == 8) // SS = A4
#define IS_PIN_SERIAL(p) ((p) == 6 || (p) == 7)
#define PIN_TO_DIGITAL(p) (p)
#define PIN_TO_ANALOG(p) (p)
#define PIN_TO_PWM(p) PIN_TO_DIGITAL(p)
#define PIN_TO_SERVO(p) (p) // deprecated since v2.4
```

I've tried to rebuild Windows Remote Arduino Experience app with modifications - I've made it log every bytes it sends to Arduino or receives from Arduino. Then I've tried sending those bytes manually but result was still the same - board was not responding

There is a device in `Device manager`:

- USB device with Serial port (COM3) (ID - `USB\VID_2886&PID_802F&REV_0104&MI_00`)

P.S. How do I know that the board is not responding and it's not the app that doesn't work? The board has RX and TX leds, RX one blinks always but TX blinks only when I use Windows Remote Arduino Experience app.

What I am doing wrong? Is there any error in setup or code I've written?

Comment: does the serial monitor in the Arduino IDE show  data from the arduino?

Comment: @jsotola Yes, when I connect the board I receive long capability message, starting with F0 6B F7

Comment: When using `Iot.Device.Arduino` I strongly recommend to use ConfigurableFirmata, as it is optimized for that. StandardFirmata may not support some features the library expects. Do note that the standard link speed has been changed to 115200 baud.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was in serial port connection settings. When I used these i was finally able to get response from board:

```csharp
var port = new SerialPort("COM3", 115600);

port.Open();

port.Parity = Parity.None;
port.StopBits = StopBits.One;
port.DataBits = 8;
port.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
port.RtsEnable = true;
port.DtrEnable = true;
port.BreakState = false;
```